# Extract content from span tag in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extact data of real state postings from https://www.lamudi.com.mx/nuevo-leon/departamento/for-rent/?page=1

I'm trying to scrape the content of bedrooms, bathrooms and square meters, using the following:

```
tags2 = soup('span',{'class':'KeyInformation-label_v2'})
for tag in tags2:
    tagl = tag.get_text().strip()
    print(tagl)
```

But I need now the actual data. This how the HTML looks (bedroom = recámara, bathroom = baño, square meters = construidos): `</span>, <span class="icon-pin"></span>, <span>Grañ Francisco Villa ote San Pedro, San Pedro Garza García</span>, <span class="PriceSection-FirstPrice">$ 7,500</span>, <span class="PriceLabel"></span>, <span class="KeyInformation-value_v2">1</span>, <span class="KeyInformation-label_v2">Recámara</span>, <span class="KeyInformation-value_v2">1</span>, <span class="KeyInformation-label_v2">Baño</span>, <span class="KeyInformation-value_v2">50 m²</span>, <span class="KeyInformation-label_v2">Construidos </span>, <span class="KeyInformation-value_v2">`

Comment: And what is your code returning? tag1.text should work

Answer (score 0):

For texts inside a tag you need to use the tag.string method

From beautiful soup [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('<b class="boldest">Extremely bold</b>', 'html.parser')
tag = soup.b
tag.string
# 'Extremely bold'
```

Answer (score 0):

The class `'KeyInformation-label_v2'` only returns the names of properties.  You need the class `'KeyInformation-value_v2'` to get the values.

You can add the title for each listing, also.  Note that there are some duplicates.

```py
titles = soup('div', {'class':'KeyInformation-attribute_v2'})
labels = soup('span', {'class':'KeyInformation-label_v2'})
values = soup('span', {'class':'KeyInformation-value_v2'})

for title, (label, value) in zip(titles, zip(labels, values)):
    print(title.find('a')['title'], label.string, value.string.strip())
```

Output:

```
Loft en Renta Amueblado Una Recámara Cerca Udem  Recámara 1
Loft en Renta Amueblado Una Recámara Cerca Udem  Baño 1
Loft en Renta Amueblado Una Recámara Cerca Udem  Construidos  50 m²
Loft en Renta Amueblado Una Recámara Cerca Udem  Recámara 1
Loft en Renta Amueblado Una Recámara Cerca Udem  Baño 1
Loft en Renta Amueblado Una Recámara Cerca Udem  Construidos  50 m²
DEPARTAMENTO EN RENTA SAN JERONIMO EQUIPADO Recámaras 3
DEPARTAMENTO EN RENTA SAN JERONIMO EQUIPADO Baños 2
...
```